# Retrieving a radiobutton label and name from the only radiobuttons checked in several groupboxes

Tags: c#, radio-button, var, groupbox

I have several group boxes, groupbox1 groupbox2 groupbox3, each one with several radio buttons.
I wanna make a list of the radio buttons that are checked across the various groupboxes, with the radiobutton name and text label. I tried the following after some research

```
    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var checkedRadio = new[] { groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3 }
              .SelectMany(g => g.Controls.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton>
                                                        ().Where(r => r.Checked));


        //print name
        foreach (var r in checkedRadio)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(r.Text, r.Name);
        }
}
```

however after selecting the radiobuttons when i press button15 nothing happens.
(I'm not sure of all the parameters, programming newbie here, so deep answers will be very welcome)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that works. In groupBox1.Controls you have a list of your elements and by iterating through them and retrieving their Checked status you can add them to a list.
Hope this helps!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Control> checkedRB = new List<Control>();

        foreach (RadioButton rb in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (rb.Checked)
                checkedRB.Add(rb);
        }

        foreach (RadioButton rb in groupBox2.Controls)
        {
            if (rb.Checked)
                checkedRB.Add(rb);
        }

        foreach (Control ctrl in checkedRB)
                Console.WriteLine(ctrl.Name);
    }
```